# fastcgi_finish_request creates hung connection when open session exists

Tags: ajax, nginx, session-state, php

I have a client side that sends a request that need long processing time, the client send the request in ajax. Once the request is accepted on the Server the client redirects to another page, this is accomplished by fastcgi_finish_request (I am running php-fpm)

LongWork.php:

```
<?php
    fastcgi_finish_request(); 
    sleep(1000); //Simulate long computation time
?>
```

client.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    data: {},
    success: function() {
        top.location.href="next_page.php" 
    }
});
```

The ajax gets sent and success callback causes redirection to next_page.php as expected.

But then the page halts and I do not get any service until the sleep is finished. It looks like my connection is waiting for the **same** php-fpm process to finish

I am running nginx with php-fpm, any Idea why this happens?

**EDIT**:

After more investigation I found the cause to this behavior is that I have a active session (from facebook SDK), When I destroy the session on LongWork.php:

```
<?php
    session_destroy(); // Session was halting the client from accessing another page
    fastcgi_finish_request(); 
    sleep(1000); //Simulate long computation time
?>
```

Can you please reflect on this solution?

Should I do something different from `session_destroy()`

**EDIT:**

following Lachlan Pease comment, I have switched `session_destroy` with `session_write_close`

Comment: Is the client using Internet Explorer? - I believe it wont terminate the connection unless you send it at least 255 characters - although maybe this was just old versions. I don't know, I don't use it.

Comment: @Leigh the problem is the session on the server, this is reproduced in every client, See Edit in question

Comment: @ekeren, you should be able to use session_write_close() to work around this instead of session_destroy() - that said, I'd still file a bug with PHP about this, it's not exactly expected behavior
EDIT: Actually, thinking about it, this is expected behavior - by default, PHP will block if a user's session is already open. Instead, you could try opening your session only when needed on the subsequent page; it's become habit to run session_start() immediately, but using output buffering you can start it on demand without ill effect.

Comment: @LachlanPease  Thanks, it worked also. What is the difference between the session_destory and session_write_close?

Comment: @ekeren The difference is that session_destroy will delete the session data on the server (i.e. delete the actual file where the session data is stored), so that when you go to the next page, the user will have a blank session. In comparison, session_write_close (or session_commit, it's other name) will just write the session data to disk and release the lock that PHP is holding on it. After that, any new changes to $_SESSION won't be changed, but anything already in there will be available on the next request.

Comment: @LachlanPease thanks for the comprehensive explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with session existence, see Edits in Questions for more details

Answer (score 0):

I have also encounter this problem, 
I register a function to run by register_shutdown_function,
and the function begin which fastcgi_finish_request ,while I found the scripts after fastcgi_finish_request() still blocking user's page, while put    session_destroy(); ahead of fastcgi_finish_request(); did work, and the user's page is not blocking any more.